# How to write wrappers for classes in c++ that overrides some member and inherits other members

Tags: c++

I want to implement a custom vector class `myVector<dataT>` which is identical to `std::vector` expect that its index starts from an offset which is given as parameter.

Example usage below:

```
myVector<int> vec(3,0,1); // length=3, initial_value=0, offset=1
assert(vec.size()==3);
vec[1]=1, vec[2]=2, vec[3]=3;
assert(vec[1]==1);
assert(vec[3]==3);
```

Basically I want to override the `dataT& operator[]` method while all other methods remain the same. But I want handle cases where `offset` is a variable instead of a constant.

If `offset` is constant, I can declare it as template parameter. But this way I cannot pass a variable as `offset`.

```
template <typename dataT, size_t offset>
class myVector{
  //definition
};

myVector<int, 1> vec; //valid
int offset=1;
myVector<int, offset> vec; //invalid
```

I have several possible way to implement `myVector` in mind, each requires some boiler-plate code:

Method 1: Inherit `std::vector`, accept `offset` as parameter of constructor

```
template <typename dataT>
class myVector : public std::vector {
  myVector(int n, int v0, int offset) {}
  dataT& operator [] (int index) {return this->at(index-offset);}
}
```

By inheriting, methods like `size, push_back` works automatically. But to accept `offset` as parameter of constructor, I have to make changes to all overloaded constructors, which can be verbose.

Method 2: Inherit `std::vector`, make `offset` a data member.

Similar to method 1, but we don't pass `offset` as constructor parameter. Instead, we use `setOffset()` to assign value to it.

While this method gets rid of most boilerplate code, every `myVector` definition requires a `setOffset`, which is also not elegant.

Method 3: `std::vector` as data member of `myVector`.

```
template <typename dataT>
class myVector {
  std::vector<dataT> stdVector;
  myVector(const std::vector<dataT> _stdVector, int offset) {}
}
```

This way definition/initialization of `myVector` becomes simple, but we need to write `myVector::size(), myVector::push_back()`, which is also verbose.

So, I have concerns about all 3 methods mentioned above. Is there any elegant implementation that both makes initialization simple and do not involve boilerplate code? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you’re trying to recreate a range/view

Comment: Don't.  Just don't.   Inheritance represents an "is-a" relationship.  You are changing the contract.  Your vector *is-not-a* vector.  Maybe create your own class that *contains* a vector.  Write all the wrapper functions you need.  Not sure if its doable (and maybe range/view is what you want as mentioned by @Taekahn), but don't inherit

Comment: Do not override any stl... If you want to use it, use composition.

Comment: @Taekahn This is just a example to showcase what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 4: make offset the ***first*** parameter to the constructor, use variadic parameters for the rest, and perfect-forward them.

```
template<typename ...Args>
myVector(int offset, Args && ...args) : std::vector{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
{
}
```

This solves the immediate problem of a single implementation for overriding all of `std::vector`'s constructors.

Now, there are other issues with subclassing `std::vector`, and all other C++ library containers which have been talked about ad-infinitum before. That may or may not be of a concern to you, you should carefully consider the implications of that (the usual objects are a lack of a virtual destructor). But, that wasn't in the scope of the original question...